# How to join an exsiting table to self-join query table?

Tags: mysql, query

This is the self-join query:

```
select g.discription, m.title 
from genre g 
join genre m on g.title = m.main_title
```

[image: the result of self-join (table 1)]

This is the table that I want to join:

```
select band.name, band.genretitel
from music_band as band
```

[image: Table 2]

the result should be like this:
[image: result]
My code is:

```
select band.name, band.genretitel
from music_band as band
left join (
select g.discription, m.title 
from genre g 
join genre m on g.title = m.main_title) disc
on band.genretitel = disc.title
```

and I get the wrong outcome :
[image: my query result]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please do **not** post images for the reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). Also, in future, please consider using a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) for you tables and data!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need a self-join.  `LEFT JOIN` allows the 'right' table to have no matching row, hence `NULLs`.

```
SELECT b.name AS Band,
       b.genretitel AS Genre,
       g.discreption AS 'Main Genre Description'
    FROM music_band AS b
    LEFT JOIN genre AS g  ON g.title = b.genretitel
```

Or...

```
SELECT b.name AS Band,
       b.genretitel AS Genre,
       ( SELECT g.discreption
            FROM genre AS g  WHERE g.title = b.genretitel
       ) AS 'Main Genre Description'
    FROM music_band AS b
```

In this case, the subquery will return `NULL` since there is no entry for `guitar`.

(In the future, please try to use text, not images.)